# CKEditor: как очистить текст от форматирования при копировании

Tags: ckeditor

Здравствуйте! При вставке текста c форматированием в поле редактора CKEditor переносится также и форматирование. Не подскажете, можно ли сделать так, чтобы форматирование не переносилось, т.е. чтобы  текст копировался как бы как из блокнота?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У хрома есть хоткей:

```
Ctrl + Shift + V
```

Также есть ластик: [Remove_Format](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Users_Guide/Document/Remove_Format)

Ну или добавьте в config.js:

```
CKEDITOR.config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли!!!!

Comment: @Mariya не таить же в себе накопленные знания :-)